# Interference during application process

Tags: applications

Person A is in the job market, far beyond entry level, requiring education and experience in the field. Person B, a good friend of A, hears of opportunities at company C. B is in contact with C, as they are doing work for B. B tells both parties about each other.

A tells B that he is going to apply.

Later in the week B sends an email to an employee at C for a different matter, but actually wants to make sure that C knows that the application they have gotten from A is from the person he knows and told them about. B says in the email that he has heard A has sent an application. The employee at C says that they haven't received anything.

A hasn't sent an application yet, and is now portrayed as less than truthful.

Can A somehow save this? And how?

(This is not about the legality of the actions, as in some juriditions it might be illegal to ask about or divulge informations about applicants).

Related: [Right time to ask somebody to drop a good word for you during interview process](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10696/right-time-to-ask-somebody-to-drop-a-good-word-for-you-during-interview-process)

Comment: Please clarify whether you are A, B or C. Hypothetical questions don't tend to lead to useful answers.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you're asking because why does A need to save anything? He told B that he is *going to* apply, and B emailed C that A has *already applied*.

Comment: For the record, this is confusing and unnecessarily complicated. Keep it simple and explain it in step-by-step timeline format if that is the issue. Sounds a like a referral issue? I can't really tell though.

Comment: Why on earth do you think that A "is now portrayed as less than truthful" ?

Comment: ok to close/delete

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem here.

> B told C (incorrectly) that A sent an application to C.

How and why would that suddenly be A's problem?  B made a fairly trivial mistake - it could happen to anyone.

If I were A, I'd send in my application and not worry about trivial matters.

Comment: Agree the only issue might be between A and B if A told B that he had sent in the application but for some reason hadn't. But that would just warrant an apology and doesn't sound like a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

> Can A somehow save this? And how?

Yes, by submitting a strong application.  If A told B that A *was going to apply* and B misheard that or misestimated the time delay for when he should shift temporal tenses, that's an understandable mistake B made.  If C notices an inconsistency, it could be attributed to B rather than A, but would still be a minor matter compared to the actual contents of the application.  If it is a big deal to C, C could ask about it at an interview, but probably they won't care, once they get your application.